# Representations of Chevalley algebras over arbitrary fields

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, chevalley-groups

In professor Humphrey’s “Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation theory” it is explained how we can reduce a semisimple complex Lie algebra (and its representations) to an arbitrary field.

Let $L$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Let $\{e_\alpha, \alpha \in \Phi; h_i, 1 \leq i \leq l\}$ be a Chevalley basis of $L$, where $l$ is the rank of $L$ and $\Phi$ its root system. Then we can take $L_\mathbb{Z}$ to be the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of this Chevalley basis. For an arbitrary field $k$, we have that $L(k) = L_\mathbb{Z} \otimes k$ defines a Lie algebra over $k$. We call $L(k)$ a Chevalley algebra.

Now let $\rho : L \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be a representation of $L$. Then we can take a suitable (i.e. admissable) $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice $V_\mathbb{Z}$ in $V$. Now let $L_V$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice inside $L$ that stabilizes $V_\mathbb{Z}$. Then we can prove that $L_V$ must be closed under the Lie bracket and therefore $L_V(k) = L_V \otimes k$ defines a Lie algebra over $k$. Moreover $$\rho_k : L_V \otimes k \to \mathfrak{gl}(V_\mathbb{Z} \otimes k) : \ell \otimes 1 \mapsto \rho(\ell) \otimes 1$$ is a representation of $L_V(k)$. Also there exists a morphism $\varphi : L_V(k) \to L(k)$ of Lie algebras. Thus $\rho_k \circ \varphi$ defines a representation of $L(k)$.

This construction ofcourse depends on the choice of the lattice $V_\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, I wonder whether we can also reduce the following situations from $\mathbb{C}$ to $k$.

1. Suppose that we have a morphism $f : V \to W$ of $L$-representations. Choose admissable lattices $V_\mathbb{Z}$ and $W_\mathbb{Z}$ for $V$ and $W$. Do we have a corresponding morphism $V_\mathbb{Z} \otimes k \to W_\mathbb{Z} \otimes k$ of $L(k)$-representations? Do we need any conditions on the admissable lattices for this to be true?
2. Let $L’\leq L$ be a reductive subalgebra of $L$ that contains the Cartan subalgebra $H = \langle h_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq l \rangle$ of $L$. Then $L’$ must be of the form $$H \oplus \langle e_\alpha \mid \alpha \in S \rangle$$ where $S$ is a closed subsystem of the root system $\Phi$. Is $L’(k)$ a subalgebra of $L(k)$?
3. Consider again the situation of 2. Let $V$ be a representation of $L$. Consider the restriction of $V$ to $L’$ and suppose $V = V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n$ is a decomposition of $V$ into $L’$-representations. Can we decompose $V_\mathbb{Z}$ as $(V_\mathbb{Z})_i \oplus \dots \oplus (V_\mathbb{Z})_n$ such that $(V_\mathbb{Z})_i \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong V_i$ for all $i$? If not in general, what if $V = V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n$ is the decomposition $V$ into $L’$-isotypic components and therefore unique? Moreover, if such a decomposition exists, is $((V_\mathbb{Z})_1 \otimes k) \oplus \dots \oplus ((V_\mathbb{Z})_n \otimes k)$ a decomposition of $V_k$ into $L’(k)$-representations?

Any help or references are appreciated.

Comment: Concerning question 1, by Schur lemma any morphism is given by a complex block matrix with blocks corresponding to isotypical components of $V$ and $W$. If it is not of the form "diagonal times integral times diagonal", it seems that arranging of admissible lattices is not possible.

Comment: @VictorPetrov What do you mean precisely when you say "diagonal times integral times diagonal"?

Comment: A matrix from $M_{nk}(\mathbb{C})$ representable as $D_1AD_2$, where $D_1\in M_{nn}(\mathbb{C})$ and $D_2\in M_{kk}(\mathbb{C})$ are diagonal and $A\in M_{nk}(\mathbb{Z})$.